# appears text when mouse is over D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

Hi everyone I am using sunburst of D3.js I want to include a text element inside each element.

For that my code is like this

```
var path = g.append("path");

if (data_key != "used"){
  svg.selectAll("g").append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d){return -50})
    .attr("dy", function(d){return 20})
    .attr("class", "all_users")
    .style("display", "none")
    .text("text");
}
```

and it works my structure is like this

```
<g>
<path style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1; fill: transparent; opacity: 0.3;" d="M0,63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,-63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,63.58917920822171Z"></path>
<text dx="-50" dy="20" class="all_users" style="display: none;">text</text>
</g>
```

I add display none to my text style, and I want to change the style (appears the text when the mouse is over this path)

for that purpose I use this

```
var g = gs.enter().append("g")
      .on("mouseover", mostrar)
```

like this

```
  function mostrar(d){
    ...
      $(this).closest('text').css("display", "inherit");

  }
```

but this `$(this).closest('text')` return an empty array `[]`. Any idea how to get the text when my mouse is over this part of the plot.

Thanks in advances

Comment: `element.textContent`? or `$element.text()`?

Comment: thank @evolutionxbox  but this don't change the style of the div, this return the value!

Comment: Ok. You've asked two questions in one. "`I want to change the style`" and "`Any idea how to get the text when my mouse is over this part of the plot.`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: this mix of D3 and jQuery is definitely not the best practice.

That being said, you can easily get the hovered element with `this`, and select the `text` with a simple selection. After that, set the style with `style`

```
d3.select(this).select("text").style("display", "inherit");
```

Here is a demo with your paths and texts:

```js
var g = d3.selectAll("g");
g.on("mouseover", show).on("mouseout", hide);

function show() {
    d3.select(this).select("text").style("display", "inherit");
}

function hide() {
    d3.select(this).select("text").style("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <g transform="translate(50,75)">
        <path style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; fill: transparent; opacity: 0.3;" d="M0,63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,-63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,63.58917920822171Z"></path>
        <text dx="-50" dy="20" class="all_users" style="display: none;">text</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(150,75)">
        <path style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; fill: transparent; opacity: 0.3;" d="M0,63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,-63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,63.58917920822171Z"></path>
        <text dx="-50" dy="20" class="all_users" style="display: none;">text</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(250,75)">
        <path style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; fill: transparent; opacity: 0.3;" d="M0,63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,-63.58917920822171A63.58917920822171,63.58917920822171 0 1,1 0,63.58917920822171Z"></path>
        <text dx="-50" dy="20" class="all_users" style="display: none;">text</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```